# R package h2o 3.13.0.356 version

Tags: r, docker, h2o

I'm running h2o from a docker image which has h2o_3.13.0.356 version. I want to command it from R but I have a different version. I can connect with the cluster but many functions don't work. 
For example `h2o.importFile` is throwing error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 412 Precondition Failed (url = http://localhost:54321/3/Parse)

water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException
[1] "water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter: decrypt_tool"                               
[2] "    water.api.Schema.fillFromParms(Schema.java:286)"                                                         
[3] "    water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:46)"                                                               
[4] "    water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:448)"                                                   
[5] "    water.api.RequestServer.doGeneric(RequestServer.java:297)"                                               
[6] "    water.api.RequestServer.doPost(RequestServer.java:223)"                                                  
[7] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                                            
[8] "    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                                            
[9] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"                                  
[10] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)"                              
[11] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)"                      
[12] "    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)"                               
[13] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)"                       
[14] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)"                           
[15] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                   
[16] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                         
[17] "    water.JettyHTTPD$LoginHandler.handle(JettyHTTPD.java:183)"                                               
[18] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)"                   
[19] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)"                         
[20] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)"                                                 
[21] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)"          
[22] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)"           
[23] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)"                
[24] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)"
[25] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)"                                        
[26] "    org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)"                                   
[27] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)"                  
[28] "    org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)"            
[29] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)"                        
[30] "    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)"                         
[31] "    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"                                                                   

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 


ERROR MESSAGE:

Unknown parameter: decrypt_tool
```

Is there any possibility to install R h2o package in the same version as the docker image has?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are using the bleeding edge version of the code (and an older build too) when we were working on an enterprise function to support encrypted data using importFile function so it is possible you have are hitting that problem. We have finished developing this feature now. So you just need to update H2O to the latest release version on your backend and R API as well.

The latest STABLE release 3.14.0.3 can be downloaded from here and please make sure you install latest H2O R Package as well:

https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-weierstrass/3/index.html

The latest bleeding is does not have this issue as well so you can try that as well.

http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/4052/index.html

[H2O 3.14.0.3 File Import Example]

```
> h2o.init()
Reading in config file: ./.h2oconfig

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: .. Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
H2O cluster uptime:         1 seconds 944 milliseconds 
H2O cluster version:        3.14.0.3 
H2O cluster version age:    12 days  
H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_avkashchauhan_hwc594 
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   3.56 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    8 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
H2O Connection port:        54321 
H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4 
R Version:                  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) 

> df = h2o.importFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/master/examples/smalldata/prostate.csv')
  |========================================================| 100%
> df
  ID CAPSULE AGE RACE DPROS DCAPS  PSA  VOL GLEASON
    1  1       0  65    1     2     1  1.4  0.0       6
    2  2       0  72    1     3     2  6.7  0.0       7
    3  3       0  70    1     1     2  4.9  0.0       6
    4  4       0  76    2     2     1 51.2 20.0       7
    5  5       0  69    1     1     1 12.3 55.9       6
    6  6       1  71    1     3     2  3.3  0.0       8

    [380 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: The docker image has an unreleased version of H2O (assuming this is a Deep Water docker image), so it will not be possible to find a matching R package.  So when you start up h2o, make sure to set `scrict_version_check = FALSE` since the Java H2O version and R h2o version will not match.

Comment: Unfortunately with STABLE and latest bleeding I'm getting exactly the same error.

Comment: Would u please confirm the latest version which gives you error?  Also please do not use Docker images as we are not updating them frequently. Also I have just edited above the 3.14.0.3 file import without a problem.

Comment: There is no problem with import, if I run cluster from R. There is a problem when I connect to the cluster which is started from docker image. I'm using docker image because I want to use well build deepwater with tensorflow and mxnet. I cannot achieve such speed when I'm building it by myself from github.